# No specific guideline for the template of first submission

Tags: paper-submission

I am planning to submit my work to [Pattern Recognition journal](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/pattern-recognition/0031-3203/guide-for-authors), and I am looking for its appropriate latex template.

I read the author guidline carefully, but honestly it is quite confusing to me. As to the template, all it says are

1. elsarticle.cls should be used for latex template
2. page limits to 20 to 35
3. double spaced and single column

Then, **I am wondering if I can change the the provided template settings when there is no specific instructions for them** Specifically,

- May I use the template from [here](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip), and am I allowed to *change its margin*? (The guideline gives no specific instruction for the margin specification at all.)
  [image]

My lab published several papers to this journal recently, however it was all done by docx using Word. What really confuses me is that the latex template provided [here](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip) has a much bigger margin size than the docx template our lab used.

I would be very grateful if someone who published to this journal using latex could give me some template advices on the first submission.

Thanks a lot for reading my question.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this.

Comment: Try making changes to the `\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}` in the elsarticle-template.tex file to get a better look, if that's what is bothering you.

Comment: I think the default template Elsevier provides has it set to what I mentioned. However, you can change it to `\documentclass[final, 2p, times]{elsarticle}` This is my personal preference in elsevier templates. It makes the paper look a bit better.

Comment: @AaqibBashir Thank a lot! So you are implicitly saying that I am allowed to change few of the template settings (for exampling, slightly reducing the margin), right?

Comment: Yes you can, however you should have in mind that the final formatting is to be done by the journal itself, if the paper is accepted. So, in my opinion doing something other than this would be just wasting time.  Unless you're making your figures, tables look better and making sure the references are not messed up. You're good to go. However, I understand the urge and eagerness to make changes/make it look more better. Trust me, it all comes down to your research results, your scientific rigour and your professional attitude towards formatting the paper. No need to sugar coat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the rules for this specific journal, but in most venues you're not supposed to tweak the page geometry (margins, headers etc.) of a template, if one is given. To me, it feels dishonest to secretly shrink the margins and squeeze in more content. It may reflect badly on you if the editor notices it.

In any case, I recommend that you contact one of the editors and ask them. That's the only way to get an authoritative answer.